# Make an arrow shape both side with xml

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I want to make a button shape like this

[image]

Is there a way to do this with `XML`?

Actually I am looking for like this

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like `chip` https://medium.com/over-engineering/hands-on-with-material-components-for-android-chips-21dc67c8b956

Comment: Something like chip but chip both sides are outside but in my case, one is inside and otherone id outer side

Comment: You can customize that

Comment: @ShivamKumar check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143905/android-make-an-arrow-shape-with-xml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264101/android-make-a-button-with-triangle-shape-using-xml-definitions-drawable

Comment: why don't you create drawable?

Comment: @ShivamKumar For the buttons (not the arc) you can use the code below. Just use `button.setBackgroundTintList(..)` to change the color of the button when you need.

Comment: @ShivamKumar, u achieved this? I also want the same.. please help me if u got the answer..

Comment: @KinjalShah Yes I have achieved this

Comment: @ShivamKumar So can you post the answer ?

Comment: @KinjalShah I have posted answer please go through this. If you have any problem then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this by `vector`.

@KinjalShah Please look into this.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="138.25dp"
    android:height="23dp"
    android:viewportWidth="138.25"
    android:viewportHeight="23">
    <path android:pathData="M132.53,22.48l-132.27,0l5.36,-10.95l-5.36,-10.94l132.27,0l5.36,10.94z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient
                android:endX="137.8946"
                android:endY="11.535"
                android:startX="0.2646"
                android:startY="11.535"
                android:type="linear">
                <item
                    android:color="#3b0b7b"
                    android:offset="0" />
                <item
                    android:color="#6244A5"
                    android:offset="1" />
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
</vector>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is not exactly what you are looking for, because it is not with realized with a XML. However with the new [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) it is very simple to obtain it:

Just define the Button in your layout:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:cornerRadius="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        .../>
```

Then just use the [**`ShapeAppearanceModel`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) to define a custom shape.

```
      float size = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cutout_size); //18dp
      TriangleEdgeTreatment triangleEdgeTreatment = new TriangleEdgeTreatment(size,true);
      CutCornerTreatment cutCornerTreatment = new CutCornerTreatment(size);

      button.setShapeAppearanceModel(button.getShapeAppearanceModel()
          .toBuilder()
          .setLeftEdge(triangleEdgeTreatment)
          .setTopRightCorner(cutCornerTreatment)
          .setBottomRightCorner(cutCornerTreatment)
          .build());
```

[image]

Using more buttons (use `button.setBackgroundTintList(..)` or `app:backgroundTint="..."` in xml to change the backgroundColor) you can obtain something like:

[image]

Comment: What is buttonTriangle??

Comment: @ShivamKumar Sorry my bad. It was just a typo. It is the button.

Comment: I'm not getting setShapeAppearanceModel parameter... how to use this ??

Comment: @Jocelin Add the material components library. It requires at least the version 1.1.0

Comment: oh my bad!! i was using 1.0.0,  will try again... thanks for the quick response though

Answer (score 0):

You can make drawable for this, this is below code which exactly you want, for the process how i have created this, you can check here in the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443999/7216511

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:viewportWidth="1870"
    android:viewportHeight="490"
    android:width="187dp"
    android:height="49dp">
    <path
        android:pathData="M0 245l0 -245 935 0 935 0 0 245 0 245 -935 0 -935 0 0 -245z"
        android:fillColor="#F99E3F" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M1 245l0 -245 934 0 935 0 0 245 0 245 -935 0 -934 0 0 -245z"
        android:fillColor="#E4CFBA" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M4 378c6 -136 6 -117 0 -260l-5 -118 935 0 936 0 0 245 0 245 -936 0 -935 0 5 -112z"
        android:fillColor="#D5D5D5" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M4 378c6 -136 6 -117 0 -260l-5 -118 935 0 936 0 0 50c0 28 -5 50 -10 50 -7 0 -7 6 0 19 6 12 10 92 9 195l-1 176 -934 0 -935 0 5 -112zm1811 -57l34 -69 -35 -76 -35 -76 -879 0c-484 0 -880 2 -880 5 0 3 15 36 34 73l34 68 -33 72 -34 72 879 0 880 0 35 -69z"
        android:fillColor="#E5DBCF" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M4 378c7 -138 7 -128 0 -265l-6 -113 936 0 936 0 0 50c0 28 -5 50 -10 50 -7 0 -7 6 0 19 13 25 13 227 0 252 -7 13 -7 19 0 19 5 0 10 22 10 50l0 50 -936 0 -936 0 6 -112zm1811 -58l35 -70 -34 -75 -35 -75 -880 0c-485 0 -881 3 -881 8 1 4 16 36 34 72l34 65 -34 67c-19 37 -34 70 -34 73 0 3 396 5 880 5l880 0 35 -70z"
        android:fillColor="#EEEEEE" />
</vector>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am looking for the above image. Please check

Comment: Then this code may work as part of the custom progress bar which you need to create